# How to install two modules (one depends on another) sequentially in one click in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developping two modules in Android Studio. Module A relies on a service of module B. Although I can install them sequentially by clicking the "run" button twice, I wonder if there is a more convenient way to automatically build and install module B at first every time module A is going to be built and installed.